# JTransforms usage in Android audio

Tags: android, audio, fft

I was looking for fast and complete DSP java libraries to use with android audio manipulation. 
i had a problem with FFT being **highly** computational. then i found JTransforms.
i caoont find documentation anywhere about how to use it. Specifically, i m confused about the input signals. in my case, i have a wav file, converted to byte array, then to double array, using this :

```
public static double[] read(byte[]file) {
    byte[] data = new byte[file.length];
    int N = data.length;
    double[] d = new double[N/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++) {
        d[i] = ((short) (((data[2*i+1] & 0xFF) << 8) + (data[2*i] & 0xFF))) / ((double) MAX_16_BIT);
    }
    return d;
}
```

but when i look at [this documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtransforms/jtransforms/2.4.0/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.java#DoubleFFT_1D.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29), i dont understand what is the input of eache method.

> Complex number is stored as two double values in sequence

Do i need to convert to Complex in order to use this library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFT audio input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369333/fft-audio-input)

Comment: this is a specific library. i am asking how to use this JTransforms library. the other question was about converting for FFt input in general.

Answer (score 2):

`DoubleFFT_1D` has methods `realForward` which take an array of real-valued samples (doubles), so you do not need to convert the input to Complex.

The [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jtransforms/jtransforms/2.4.0/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.java#DoubleFFT_1D.realForward%28double%5B%5D%29) you linked further describes the input requirements which are different depending on if you use `realForward(double[])` or `realForward(double[], int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing DSP in Java is way slower than doing it in NDK with a well optimized library.

The Superpowered Audio SDK has many DSP features, including an FFT which outperforms Apple’s vDSP.

Especially if you’d like to receive magnitudes and phases.

Check the SuperpoweredPolarFFT method: http://superpowered.com/docs/_superpowered_f_f_t_8h.html#a0b63c427504bcbbd9ead8a2ff58daf62

Comment: i like the idea of your project. i had lots of trouble with audio on android. i still have weird delays while recording though, takes sometimes 500ms before it really starts recording.

Comment: Take a look and let me know what you think!