# Low pass filter with directsound implementation issue

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, directsound, lowpass-filter

Currently I am developing a c# low pass filter in real time using directsound API. The problem that I've encountered is that various implementations of low pass filters seem not to work with my echo implementation. At the begining of the filtering I have an array of bytes (read) that is read from the capturing buffer. The values of this array are between 0 and 255.

When I subject the array to low-pass filtering algorithm I obtain values that fall between 0 and 1 and as an effect the play array is silent (zeros only). I attach the relevant code.

I imagine that that this approach is wrong and probably the input data should look different as the low pass algorithm seems to kill it completely. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Updated relevant code after KillaKem's comments:**

```
//buffer format
var format = new WaveFormat
        {
            SamplesPerSecond = 44100,
            BitsPerSample = 16,
            Channels = 2,
            FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm
        };

//reading the buffer
         byte[] read = (byte[])_dwCapBuffer.Read(offset, typeof(byte), LockFlag.None, _dwOutputBufferSize);
                    byte[] play = new byte [read.Length];
                    byte[] readL= new byte [read.Length/2];
                    byte[] readR= new byte [read.Length/2];
                    byte[] playL = new byte[read.Length / 2];
                    byte[] playR = new byte[read.Length / 2];
                    float[] readLfloat = new float[read.Length / 4];
                    float[] readRfloat = new float[read.Length / 4];
                    float[] playLfloat = new float[read.Length / 4];
                    float[] playRfloat = new float[read.Length / 4];

//dividing into channels and casting to float
                    for(int i = 0; i<read.Length; i=i+1)
                    {
                        if (i % 4 == 0)
                        {
                            readL[(int)i / 2] = read[i];
                        }
                        if(i%4==1)
                        {
                        readL[(int)i/2]=read[i];
                        readLfloat[(int)i / 4] = (((short)(read[i-1] << 8 | read[i])) / 32768f);
                        }
                        if (i % 4 == 2)
                        {
                            readR[(int)i / 2] = read[i];
                        }
                        if (i % 4 == 3)
                        {
                            readR[(int)i / 2] = read[i];
                            readRfloat[(int)i / 4] = (((short)(read[i - 1] << 8 | read[i])) / 32768f);
                        }

                    }
//filter coefficients
float frequency = 1000f;
                    float sampleRate = (float)_dwCapBuffer.Format.SamplesPerSecond;
                    float resonance = 0.5f;

                    float c = 1.0f / (float)Math.Tan(Math.PI * frequency / sampleRate);
                    float a0 = 1.0f / (1.0f + resonance * c + c * c);
                    float a1 = 2f * a0;
                    float a2 = a0;
                    float b1 = 2.0f * (1.0f - c * c) * a0;
                    float b2 = (1.0f - resonance * c + c * c) * a0;
//filtering
for(int i = 0; i < readLfloat.Length; i++)
                    {

                        float readCurrSample = readLfloat[i];
                        float playCurrSample = playLfloat[i];
                        float filtered=readCurrSample;
                        float readOneSample;
                        float readTwoSample;
                        float playOneSample;
                        float playTwoSample;


                        if (i ==0)
                        {
                            filtered = ((float)a0 * readCurrSample) + ((float)a1 * savelastRead) + ((float)a2 * saveprelastRead) - ((float)b1 * savelastPlay) - ((float)b2 * saveprelastPlay);

                        }
                        else if (i==1)
                        {
                            readOneSample = readLfloat[i-1];
                            playOneSample = playLfloat[i-1];
                            filtered = ((float)a0 * readCurrSample) + ((float)a1 * readOneSample) + ((float)a2 * savelastRead) - ((float)b1 * playOneSample) - ((float)b2 * savelastPlay);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            readOneSample = readLfloat[i - 1];
                            playOneSample = playLfloat[i - 1];

                            readTwoSample = readLfloat[i - 2];

                            playTwoSample = playLfloat[i - 2];
                            filtered = ((float)a0 * readCurrSample) + ((float)a1 * readOneSample) + ((float)a2 * readTwoSample) - ((float)b1 * playOneSample) - ((float)b2 * playTwoSample);

                        }

                        if (i == readL.Length - 4)
                        {

                            saveprelastPlay = playCurrSample;
                            saveprelastRead = readCurrSample;
                        }
                        if (i == readL.Length-2)
                        {
                            savelastPlay = playCurrSample;
                            savelastRead = readCurrSample;
                        }
                        if (filtered > 1 || filtered < -1)
                        {
                            int x = 0;
                        }

                        playLfloat[i] = filtered;


                    }

                    playRfloat = playLfloat; //ignoring Right channel operations
//Recasting to bytes array

                    for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i = i + 1)
                    {


                        if (i % 4 == 1)
                        {
                            byte[] bytes;

                            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(playLfloat[(int)(i-1)/4] * 32768f));
                            read[i] = bytes[0];
                            read[i - 1] = bytes[1];

                        }

                        if (i % 4 == 3)
                        {
                            byte[] bytes;

                            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(playRfloat[(int)(i - 1) / 4] * 32768f));
                            read[i] = bytes[0];
                            read[i - 1] = bytes[1];
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: I think you are having problems with scaling, an audio sample is actually between -1 and 1 but it often represented as a number between 0 and 255, you need to convert your audio to floating point samples between -1 and 1 before applying your low pass filter.What is the BitDepth (the number of bits in each audio sample) of your audio?

Comment: Hi KillaKem,
Thanks for answering on such short notice. My bits per sample  is set to 16.  How to convert my data to floating points?

Comment: If you have 16Bits per sample then every byte you read from a stream represents only one half of a sample.So you have to 2 bytes to form one sample.Furthermore, if your audio recording has 2 channels instead of one then the samples for the left and right channels are interleaved in the audio stream, you might want to first separate them before first doing any audio processing.

Comment: The Q&A might give you clues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403764/audio-sampling-rate-of-an-ip-camera-and-fft/24405150#24405150

Comment: @KillaKem: Are the channels interleaved in such way - {right,left,right,left} or in some other manner? Currently trying to implement casting as you've kindly described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369333/fft-audio-input/24373897#24373897

Comment: UPDATE:
I've followed your advice and:
1. Divided the buffer into two channels [right,left,right, left] - let me know if it's the correct approach.
2. Casted the bytes into floats

However, the result array (one channel, already casted) gives values from 0.0 to 2.0, so not -1 to 1 audio samples that we would like to have. Any ideas?

Comment: Dividing the into 2 channels is right if your audio has 2 channels and not just 1 channel Mono.If you are getting values from 0 to 2 then you are doing the casting wrong somehow.Instead of worrying about using floating point numbers, for now you can just use shorts and do the casting just as it is done in the sample Q&A you were looking at, since shorts are exactly 16bits and you are using 16bit audio everything should go smoothly.Note that a short can take values from -32768 to 32767 and so dividing a short by 32768 (the maximum absolute value of a short) will give a value between -1 and 1.

Comment: @KillaKem: Thanks again. I think I got the casting to work, because now I have values in "-0.9 to 0.9 range". Yes, my audio is 2-channeled. One more question - is the buffer interleaved at byte[] stage or at float[]? So that I perform the split in a right moment.

Comment: It is interleaved at the sample level, i.e the first 2 bytes belong to the first sample of the first channel, the next 2 bytes belong to the first sample of the 2nd channel e.t.c

Comment: @KillaKem: Above I've submitted an updated and broader code version. Can you take a look at it? Even though the float values are in the right range -1 to 1 they seem odd (they are mainly zeros) and when getting filtered they only turn to speaker-blasting white-ish noise. Any ideas?

Comment: Your conversion from bytes to floats looks OK but I might be failing to spot a mistake in your code, you might want to use the "Convert16BitToFloat" and the "StereoToMono" methods on this page (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET) and compare the values you get using those methods to the values you get with your casting algorithm, if the results match up then the problem is in your Low-Pass filtering.