# How can I decode raw f32 audiosamples, so that I can extract the volume of a specific frequenzy?

Tags: audio, rust

I am currently working on an equalizer which takes the input of a microphone in rust using [cpal](https://crates.io/crates/cpal) as audio backend.

I am capturing the raw data and sending it to another thread like this:

```
pub fn init(sender: mpsc::Sender<bridge::Event>) {
    let host = cpal::default_host();
    let input_device = host.default_input_device().unwrap();

    println!("Using input device: \"{}\"", input_device.name().unwrap());

    let config: cpal::StreamConfig = input_device.default_input_config().unwrap().into();

    println!(
        "Attempting to build both streams with f32 samples and `{:?}`.",
        config
    );

    let input_data_fn = move |data: &[f32], _: &cpal::InputCallbackInfo| {
        for &sample in data {
            sender.send(bridge::Event::Push(sample * 5.0)).unwrap();
        }
    };

    let input_stream = input_device.build_input_stream(&config, input_data_fn, err_fn).unwrap();

    input_stream.play().unwrap();

    loop {}
}

fn err_fn(err: cpal::StreamError) {
    eprintln!("an error occurred on stream: {}", err);
}
```

This seems to work perfectly fine and sends a lot of floats which correspond to the overall volume in my room to the receiving thread.

But I have no experience in audio processing and no clue how to approach this problem

I already looked at this crate [dasp](https://crates.io/crates/dasp) but it just doesnt take me any further.

So what do I have to do to extract the volume of any given frequenzy at any time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an equalizer I'd use an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm implementation.

There are libraries for Rust, e.g. https://github.com/ejmahler/RustFFT. You can find more on [crates.io](https://crates.io/search?q=fft&sort=recent-downloads).

In your code you are sending samples one by one, but the FFT expects a buffer (a sequence of samples during some short period of time). Given a buffer it outputs the frequencies graph in this time frame.

If you give it a sliding time window, then the repeating frequencies will be averaged, and it should show what you expect from a typical EQ. A ring buffer could be useful to collect samples in this sliding window (e.g. [this one](https://docs.rs/dasp/0.11.0/dasp/ring_buffer/index.html) from dasp)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am now sending buffers with the length of 3764 instead of single samples, but I dont fully understand how to deal with the FFT algorithm with RustFFT. Could you maybe give me a simple example on how to do this?

Comment: I see that RustFFT takes Vec<Complex> as input and outputs Vec<Complex> (in place). People [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369333/fft-audio-input) suggest to pass `im: 0`, and `re: sample` as input. On the outputs call [`.norm()`](https://docs.rs/num-complex/0.3.1/num_complex/struct.Complex.html#method.norm) to get the frequency amplitude.